# Sorting in mongoDB on basis of Order No

Tags: mongodb

I have a collectiton "A" with this document:

```
 {
   "InsuranceCompany" : {
      "fieldlabel" : "InsuranceCompany",
      "fieldname" : "InsuranceCompany",
      "fieldtype" : "dropdown",
      "required" : "1",
      "default_value" : "",
      "placeholder" : "InsuranceCompany",
      "order_no" : "3",
      "formgroup" : "policyDetails",
      "can_delete" : "1",
      "status" : "1"
   },
   "PolicyNumber" : {
      "fieldlabel" : "PolicyNumber",
      "fieldname" : "PolicyNumber",
      "fieldtype" : "text",
      "required" : "1",
      "default_value" : "",
      "placeholder" : "Policy Number",
      "order_no" : "1",
      "formgroup" : "policyDetails",
      "can_delete" : "1",
      "status" : "1"
   },
   "NoOfYear" : {
      "fieldlabel" : "NoOfYear",
      "fieldname" : "NoOfYear",
      "fieldtype" : "text",
      "required" : "1",
      "default_value" : "",
      "placeholder" : "No Of Year",
      "order_no" : "2",
      "formgroup" : "policyDetails",
      "can_delete" : "1",
      "status" : "1"
   }
}
```

i want to sort it on the basis of order_no that is my result should be:

```
{
  "PolicyNumber" : {
      "fieldlabel" : "PolicyNumber",
      "fieldname" : "PolicyNumber",
      "fieldtype" : "text",
      "required" : "1",
      "default_value" : "",
      "placeholder" : "Policy Number",
      "order_no" : "1",
      "formgroup" : "policyDetails",
      "can_delete" : "1",
      "status" : "1"
   },
   "NoOfYear" : {
      "fieldlabel" : "NoOfYear",
      "fieldname" : "NoOfYear",
      "fieldtype" : "text",
      "required" : "1",
      "default_value" : "",
      "placeholder" : "No Of Year",
      "order_no" : "2",
      "formgroup" : "policyDetails",
      "can_delete" : "1",
      "status" : "1"
   },
   "InsuranceCompany" : {
      "fieldlabel" : "InsuranceCompany",
      "fieldname" : "InsuranceCompany",
      "fieldtype" : "dropdown",
      "required" : "1",
      "default_value" : "",
      "placeholder" : "InsuranceCompany",
      "order_no" : "3",
      "formgroup" : "policyDetails",
      "can_delete" : "1",
      "status" : "1"
   }
}
```

I have tried this query:

```
db.A.aggregate([
{ $sort : { order_no : -1 } }
]).pretty()
```

But it didn't work for me as it is returning the same sequence.

Comment: Are the 3 higher level properties `PolicyNumber`, `NoOfYear` and `InsuranceCompany` dynamic?

Comment: Yes all are dynamic and can be increased thats why i giving order_no so that user can manage the filed priority.

Comment: With this schema it's hardly possible to query using MongoDB as you need to know the field names beforehand. You can however redesign your schema in such a way that you have an array field, say `orders` which holds the subdocuments e.g. `{ "orders": [ {  "fieldlabel" : "NoOfYear",  "fieldname" : "NoOfYear", "order_no" : 2, ... }, { "fieldlabel" : "InsuranceCompany", .. } ] }`

Comment: Thanks ! But i have to follow the same structure as per the requirement

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. You're showing one document and asking about sorting the subdocument fields within it, but field order has no meaning in MongoDB. Why do you care what the order of the fields are?

Comment: You can't do that you can use $project aggregation stage and decide the order manual ,otherwise manage it in clientside